# Extracting files downloaded as a dependency in Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I've got a gradle script that goes something like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

defaultTasks 'build'

ext.basedir = file('.').getAbsolutePath()

repositories{    
    maven { url "http://package.repo.com:8081/nexus/content/repository
}

configurations.all {
    // check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

dependencies {
compile group:'com.repo.wwpd', name:'kernel_utilities', version:'3.0.0', changing:true
}

task copy_dependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into basedir+'\\install'
    include '*'
    { FileTree ioTree = fileTree(dir: "C:\\Users\\username\\install") }

    ioTree.each { f ->
       copy {
           from tarTree(resources.gzip(f))
            into "C:\\Users\\user\\test"
      }
   }
}
```

The goal is to get the dependencies, move them to the install folder, and extract them from the tar files to the test folder.

The problem appears to be that the task is executed before the dependencies are downloaded. So if the files already exist in install it works fine, but if the install folder is empty the result is an empty test folder but a full install folder.

Comment: [1] do you need both the downloaded (in installDir) and the extracted ? [2] note: 'ext.basedir' can be replaced by projectDir (gradle project property).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT - updated with comments Peter N.]
This should be one way to solve your case ; note it contains two tasks, choose the one(s) that fulfill your needs: simple copy VS full extraction

```
  def installDir = "${buildDir}/install"
  def extractDir = "${buildDir}/extract"

  // task to copy dependencies
  task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into installDir
  }

  // task to extract dependencies
  task extractDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile.collect{tarTree (it)}
    into extractDir
  }
```

Comment: BTW: I would also define installDir and extractDir relative to 'buildDir' iso 'projectDir'.

Comment: The `doLast` part should be turned into its own task. Unless `installDir` is needed by users of the build, the extra copying step can be avoided, as you indicated in your comment.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: your suggestion to move the doLast part in another task is purely out of a "design principle", I guess. Or is there another, technical (..) reason ?

Comment: Design and technical. In particular, the current task's up-to-date check won't work correctly. The task will be up-to-date even if `extractDir` has been blown away. Instead of manually registering `extractDir` as an output dir, it's better to turn this into its own task. (And unless `installDir` is essential, that intermediate step should be removed altogether.)

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, thx for the feedback, makes sense indeed; will update answer accordingly.